# How to execute tasks sequentially in celery based on a parameter?

Tags: django, concurrency, celery, django-celery

I am currently working on a data polling app in which we have some 600-700 different data sources. We have a client installed at every source location which periodically collects data and sends a CSV file to the server. At server, we receive the CSV and process the data later using celery tasks.

We have currently 10 celery workers running on the server which handle one file each simultaneously.

Although, we do want this concurrency yet we would also like to implement celery in such a way data files from one source should always be processed sequentially. That means, if the files are from same data source 2nd file should always be processed only after 1st file is completely processed.

Does celery provide such an option or I need to build some custom queue management solution?

**Note**: I am currently using Celery with Django.

Comment: Celery doesn't support sequential execution of tasks, unless you only run 1 worker. You could create one queue per worker, and route tasks into different queues based on their arguments, where you always route a task for a specific data source to the same route.
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.5/userguide/routing.html#routers

Comment: Looks like I can make use of it. Thank you @NicoGriffioen